# How to get Main Screen after login when you have logged out from a dwawer Navigation Screen in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, navigation-drawer, stack-navigator

I have a Main screen which comes after login. There is a drawer Navigator which contains a Second Screen and Logout. When I go to the Second screen and then open drawer navigator and click on logout then after i login again, the Second screen is opened instead of the main screen.
I want the Main Screen to open even though I logout from the second screen. How is this possible?

Flow ->
Login -> MainScreen -> DrawerNavigator -> SecondScreen ->Logout -> Login -> SecondScreen

I want HomeScreen not SecondScreen after Second login

Comment: This is a good question but feels a little hard to read your navigation logic. Reforming your question with a diagram of your navigation might be a big help. Like:
Login -> Main -> Drawer Navigator -> Second Screen

Answer (score 1):

By default, when you navigate a screen in the nested navigator, the specified screen is used as the initial screen and the initial route prop on the navigator is ignored.
If you need to render the initial route specified in the navigator, you can disable the behavior of using the specified screen as the initial screen by setting `initial: false`

You can read more about this [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#rendering-initial-route-defined-in-the-navigator)

You should also refer React Navigation Docs for [Authentication Flows](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow) to design authentication mechanism for your app.